# How to trigger an Update Panel without Page Loading all again

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the thing:

I have a Master Page, and a couple of other Web Forms. All of them invoke User Controls, and inside the User Controls, there is an Update Panel.

Now that I add a button in the Master Page (all the pages will need that button, that's why it is in the Master Page), I need that button to show a Popup. That's ok.

The problem is that when I click the button, the page rendered again. So I put the button inside an Update Panel and set it as an Async Trigger for the Update Panel.

(imagine something like that: 
  Master page{
          update panel {
                button
            }
          content place holder
      }
)

Now the page does not render again, but still launch the Page Load, and that is a problem.
If a page takes 5 seconds to show, because it is loading the content, the button in the master page will take 5 seconds too, because it will load all again.

Does someone know something to fix that?

Comment: You should avoid using UpdatePanel in the first place. You will constantly run into all sorts of issues like this. You would be far better off learning how to do proper AJAX calls instead of using a magic abstraction that doesn't fit well with the web programming model.

Comment: The problem is that this is not my project, it's from my work. I can't change this kind of thing, so it has to be with an update panel

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's an asp.net standard button like

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

So on click of this button it fires a postback event. But the button needs to show a popup only and if no server code processing is required, better to use

```
<input type="button" id="Button1" value="Button"/>
```

Remove UpdatePanel.

Comment: It needs to go to the server. This popup will bring dats from the database